# How to set a legend and other attributes while plotting several pandas data frames in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, legend

I have a list of data frames that I would like to plot in the same graph in 2 ways each. I started with a simple line plot that was hard to understand and a scatterplot that was similarly confusing. My idea was to combine the 2 to see the data points and have them connected like so:
[Both scatter and lineplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vslyj.png)

Plotted with this code right here:

```
    #set common Coordinate System
    ax = plt.gca()

    #create apropriate colour map
    #set how many levels of shades are allowed
    shade_level = len(zreal_zimg_dfs) * 100 + 1
    shades = np.arange(shade_level)
    #create Normalize object for mappable (necessary)
    norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=shades.min(), vmax=shades.max())
    #create colourmap that creates all levels of shade of a certain colour
    shades = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.Blues)

    # x determines what shade of the colour to be used last (in percent; e.g. 0.15 == 15% colour)
    x = 0.25

    #'colourstep' to take to be equally 'spaced'
    shade_step = int(shade_level * (1-x) / len(zreal_zimg_dfs))

    #plot, set label, marker and linesizes and colours
    for i in range(len(zreal_zimg_dfs)):
        #plot the markerpoints (scatter)
        zreal_zimg_dfs[i].plot( x = 'Zreal1', y = 'Zimg1', ax = ax, label = '{nr}. {date}'.format(nr = i+1, date = dates[i]),
                                xlabel = 'Z-Realteil (mOhm)', ylabel = 'Z-Imaginärteil (mOhm)',
                                color = shades.to_rgba(max(shade_level - i * shade_step, shade_level * x)),
                                kind = 'scatter', marker = '.', s = 8)
        
        zreal_zimg_dfs[i].plot( x = 'Zreal1', y = 'Zimg1', ax = ax,
                                color = shades.to_rgba(max(shade_level - i * shade_step, shade_level * x)),
                                linewidth = 0.2, legend = False)

    #ax.legend(loc = 'upper right', frameon = False)
    plt.title('Impedanz NMC{nmc_nr} Test EIS{EIS_nr}'.format(nmc_nr = nmc_nr, EIS_nr = EIS_nr))
    plt.savefig('Impedanz NMC{nmc_nr} Test EIS{EIS_nr}.png'.format(nmc_nr = nmc_nr, EIS_nr = EIS_nr), dpi = 600)
    plt.show()
```

Much of this code deals with creating the colour map, so don't get confused. My problem arises when I try to adjust the legend of the Plot. Notice the commented
`ax.legend(loc = 'upper right', frameon = False)`

Upon uncommenting this the legend is messed up completely. I have tried this with plt.legend as well but got the same messed up result:

[Legend messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrRRT.png)

I'm not sure what the problem is here but to be honest I have a hard time understanding how pandas plot and regular matplotlib interact and what exactly the differences between fig, ax and plt are. Any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Matplotlib features are weird when plots are made with Pandas. It is sometimes better to use Matplotlib OOP style. When you put `ax.legend()` that will remake the legend, no matter you put `legend=False` in the lines plots. For this case, I would recommend you get the handlers of the legend and then select only what you need. This is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
ax = plt.gca()

for i in range(1, 5):
    df.plot(x='col0', y=f'col{i}', kind = 'scatter', marker = '.', s = 20, ax=ax, color=f'C{i}', label=f'scater {i}')
    df.plot(x='col0', y=f'col{i}', linewidth = 1, legend = False, ax=ax, color=f'C{i}')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[4:], labels[4:], loc ='upper left', frameon = False, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem, although it feels a bit clunky. Can you elaborate a bit on what handles are? I printed both handles and labels and while labels is easy enough to understand I did not get what the handles are

Comment: The handles contain the graphic elements to be drawn. More info here: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html